# Injeolmi - Korean Sweet Rice Cakes

Tags: baking, substitutions, dessert, korean-cuisine, sticky-rice

I have never made injeolmi before but am keen to try - I have a few questions though before I try:

- steaming vs microwaving the rice dough? I imagine it gets uber sticky in the steamer, a recipe suggested a cotton towel, but wouldn't that ruin the towel?
- I don't have toasted soybean flour - any substitution recommendations? I was thinking matcha and icing sugar/ cocoa powder and icing sugar. But I do have canned beans I could drain and oven dry or dehydrate and then powder?
- when 'pounding' the dough, what is the best method? What consistency and texture am I looking for?
- I'd like to stuff it with sweet red bean paste, any advice for best method/recipe for this?

Thanks all!

Comment: Seriouseat's Bravetart suggests toasted soy flour as a substitution for malted milk powder, so I would guess the reverse also work.

Answer (score 2):

1. The steamed dough is just as sticky! The steam is what adds the moisture to the dough as it gets steamed. Microwaved dough just tends to require more water, because  microwaved dough doesn't get water replenished during the microwaving process.
2. Toasted soybean flour itself has NO substitute. If you have raw soybean flour, sift it, roast it in a dry pan, season it with a pinch of salt, and let it cool before using. However, as the gomul (고물) ingredient for injeolmi, you can alternatively use toasted sesame powder. Black sesame seeds will work better than white, if you prefer a more unique color.
3. Use a pestle, and keep pounding until the dough starts turning more elastic than goopy.
4. Adding red bean paste inside will change the recipe! Don't use any stuffing!

Traditionally speaking, injeolmi only consists of *tteok* and the powder on the outside. Injeolmi is eaten "plain", or dipped in rice syrup or honey on the side.